# SQL count total

Tags: mysql, sql

```
+--------+-------+----------+-----------+
| Maker  | Model | SeatType | NoOfSeats |
+--------+-------+----------+-----------+
| Airbus | 340   | E        |       220 |
| Airbus | 340   | F        |        20 |
| Airbus | 380   | E        |       300 |
| Airbus | 380   | F        |        60 |
| Boeing | 747   | E        |       300 |
| Boeing | 747   | F        |        40 |
| Boeing | 777   | E        |       200 |
| Boeing | 777   | F        |        20 |
| Boeing | 787   | E        |       250 |
| Boeing | 787   | F        |        25 |
+--------+-------+----------+-----------+
```

Below is my attempt to create a query of this "PlaneSeats" table

```
select Maker, count(distinct Model)
from PlaneSeats 
group by Maker, Model 
having SUM(NoOfSeats) > 350;
```

and here is the result query

```
+--------+-----------------------+
| Maker  | count(distinct Model) |
+--------+-----------------------+
| Airbus |                     1 |
+--------+-----------------------+
```

but what I want to get is the Maker and total number of planes made by this maker, also for Makers who make any plane with total number of seats more than 350. I understand the count should be 2 here instead of 1 since there are 2 models for Maker Airbus. Please help me find out where it's wrong. Thank you.

Comment: you are getting count 1 because Maker Airbus with model "380" has 360 seats but Boeing Maker's any of model doesn't have seats more then 350.

Comment: @Poorva Yes I understand that part by looking at the table. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need two levels of aggregation:

```
select maker, count(*)
from (select maker, model, sum(NoOfSeats) as numseats
      from planeseats ps
      group by maker, model
     ) mm
where numseats > 350
group by maker;
```

EDIT:

You want all planes to be counted for a make when one is big enough.  That means turning the `where` to a `having` clause:

```
select maker, count(*)
from (select maker, model, sum(NoOfSeats) as numseats
      from planeseats ps
      group by maker, model
     ) mm
group by maker
having max(numseats) > 350;
```

Comment: Could you explain more on this 2 levels of aggregation, please? Also I tried to put the above code in and it turns out to be 1 instead of 2.

Comment: I *think* the OP wants the total number of models made by the manufacturer, regardless of the number of seats - as long as at least one model had in excess of 350 seats.